# Frozen user accounts

Tags: account, user, user-management, userlicense

When people leave our company, their Salesforce user accounts are deactivated.
I uncheck the 'active' checkbox, Save, then finally check the checkboxes below:
[image]

We are running into problems when people leave the company but they own dashboards/have forecasts that roll up to them, or they have subscribed reports that get sent out if we make them inactive then none of these work. As a workaround to this, I have 'Frozen' these accounts - but I am only made aware that I need to freeze an account when we run into problems with access issues to dashboards/reports.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, It's based on `maintenance` of your SFDC org components with users. As you already mentioned, `Freezing` user and finding his dependencies is one of the way.

Other one is, You can updating his email address as your(Admin) email address to identify the user dependencies before you can deactivate that user. (update `username` or `federation Identifier` also for prevent login attempt from that user).

Then after you can able to identify the following things based on that user,

- Scheduled reports
- Pending approval records
- Dashboard Running users

Then you can able to update those things with the alternative user who can tale his role in forward days.

And You can use `Delegated Approver` option in user object also for identify the pending approval requests for that user (but it's only working based on approval process settings and current pending request's only).

Please let me know if it helps.